# How automatically refresh only one module in joomla?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla

How **automatically refresh** only one **module** in joomla?

```
  <?php if ($this->countModules('parite')) : ?>
                    <section id="parite" >

                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="parite" style="xhtml" />

                    </section>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing? Could you please give us more context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was the answer I was looking for.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
 jQuery('#parite').load('<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/modules/mod_parite/mod_parite.php');     

}, 1000);
</script>
<div id="parite"></div>
```